# Symfony2 functional test case not covering custom dependency injection config parameters

Tags: dependency-injection, phpunit, symfony-2.8

I have created a custom bundle with yml structure, and for the sake of the bundle usuage, I created a new array-set of config parameters and hence I wrote DependencyInjection/Configuration.php and DependencyInjection/MyConfigParamExtension.php.

I am crawling the site with WebTestCase extended cases, using a crawler to go to routes.

Now in my bundle code I have used the config parameters like:

$this->container->getParameter('my_search_params');

I expected the DependencyInjection classes will get covered by the test cases, but it is not the case.

Please advise me with you suggestions to improve the same.

Answer (score 0):

The [SymfonyDependencyInjectionTest](https://github.com/SymfonyTest/SymfonyDependencyInjectionTest) by Matthias Noback works for me

Though its is recommended to avoid dependency injection and move all bundle specific configurations to parameters tag in config.yml